# How to force animation on chartjs?

Tags: javascript, animation, chart.js

I have charts grouped under tab (based on [this](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_tabs_dynamic&stacked=h))  like this:
[image: charts]
When I reload the page or update values, animation works well. But I would like to start animation when I open tab with charts.
Is it possible?

I tried to use 
`chart.update()` or `chart.render()` but nothing work.

Comment: You can use the chart.js deferred plugin which loads the animation only when the chart is on the viewport -> https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-deferred

Comment: this does not work for me :(

Comment: Deferred plugin works fine, but only until chartjs 2.9.4! Took me a while to get this.

Answer (score 1):

There is possible solution if you destroy charts and create a new one.

```
 Chart.helpers.each(Chart.instances, function(chart){
    let ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
    let config = chart.config;
    chart.destroy();
    new Chart(ctx, config);
})
```

It will get all chart instances so you can easy get config and ctx of charts. Just put this in function what you call when you click on tab.

Answer (score 0):

Define your chart with a 'this':

```
this.myChartInstance = new Chart(ctx, { ...
```

Then use a Javascript call in the:

```
<li><a data-toggle="tab" onclick="update" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
```

and call the script to re-animate ...

```
function update() {
    this.myChartInstance.update();
}
```